# FFMPEG: Two smaller IP cameras with background of another camera, stream to youtube

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, camera

I want to do something like this:

```
          ---------------
          |  1 |    | 2 |
          |----|    |---|
          | Main Camera |
          ---------------
```

Two smaller cameras in the corners and the background is another camera

I have something like this:

```
ffmpeg 
-i "rtsp://............" 
-i "rtsp://............"
-i "rtsp://............"
-f lavfi -i anullsrc  
-filter_complex "
[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=1920x1080,setsar=1[center]; 
[1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=640x480,setsar=1[upperright];
[2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=640x480,setsar=1[upperleft];  
[upperleft][upperright]hstack[base]" 
-map [base] -map 2 -f flv "rtmp://......................"
```

OR

```
ffmpeg
    -i 1.avi -i 2.avi -i 3.avi -i 4.avi
    -filter_complex "
        nullsrc=size=640x480 [base];
        [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperleft];
        [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperright];
        [2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerleft];
        [3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerright];
        [base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1];
        [tmp1][upperright] overlay=shortest=1:x=320 [tmp2];
        [tmp2][lowerleft] overlay=shortest=1:y=240 [tmp3];
        [tmp3][lowerright] overlay=shortest=1:x=320:y=240
    "
    -c:v libx264 output.mkv
```

But obviously it won't work, smth need to be changed but I'm not so experienced with the `ffmpeg`, so could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I would use OBS Studio.  It's free, open source, available in the repos and has built in support for streaming.  You can and overlay multiple video sources on top of each other (picture in picture or PiP), etc.

Comment: But its not for a streaming my desktop nor my face but my three cameras IP and i'm using my raspberry pi to stream a single one of them right now but i would like to add to this another two cameras. So i don't think so that OBS is for such purpose.

Comment: OBS takes video input from a variety of sources. It didn't have to be your desktop or a webcam. I've even used it to capture footage from my VCR to back up old home movies. I'm pretty sure there's even plugins to connect to IP cameras.

Comment: Okey then ill give it a try, but does it support ubuntu server or any other linux distro?
I want to host it 24h/7 i want to make a live cam.

Comment: I believe it is a gui only application so you'd have to have a graphical desktop installed. It runs on it much everything though, Windows, Linux, OSX, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
ffmpeg -i left -i right -i background -i anullsrc -filter_complex \
"[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=640:-1[left]; \
 [2:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=640:-1[right]; \
 [0:v][left]overlay=shortest=1[bg];[bg]overlay=shortest=1:x=W-w[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 3:a -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:v <> -maxrate <> -bufsize <> -g <> -f flv rtmp://...
```

- Enter appropriate values for each instance of `<>`. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Live Streaming](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites) for more info and examples.
- As for the 2x2 grid see [Vertically or horizontally stack several videos using ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33764934/1109017)